# Update Field in Database A With Field From Database B and Avoiding Safe Update Warning

Tags: mysql, workbench

I want to update the field `xfade` in `samdb.songlist` with the values from `xfade` in another database (on the same host), `samdbtmp.songlisttmp`. As long as there is the text `APPLE` in the `filename` field.

Here is my attempt...

```
UPDATE samdb.songlist
SET 
    samdb.songlist.xfade = (SELECT 
            samdbtmp.songlisttmp.xfade
        FROM
            samdbtmp.songlisttmp
        WHERE
            samdbtmp.songlisttmp.ID = samdb.songlist.ID)
WHERE filename LIKE '%201411.mp3';
```

I would like to do this without taking off safe updates in Workbench, and I thought by adding the WHERE, with key field `ID`, I should be able to do that. But I get error...

`Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.`

Question... is my MySQL correct? And how do I avoid the error?

Comment: This is a Workbench error message and it quite clear as to how to alter the behavour. So I am unsure what the question really is.

Comment: "`you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column`". I though I was using a `WHERE` that uses a key column, `ID`. Or do I need a second `WHERE` outside the `SET`?

Comment: Your WHERE is only directly applied to the sub-query. The UPDATE will update ALL rows in the table, which may or may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: OK I updated, but just realised my WHERE isn't a key column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer as much as a workaround. I went with the below...

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE samdb.songlist
SET 
    samdb.songlist.xfade = (SELECT 
            samdbtmp.songlisttmp.xfade
        FROM
            samdbtmp.songlisttmp
        WHERE
            samdbtmp.songlisttmp.ID = samdb.songlist.ID)
WHERE filename LIKE '%201411.mp3';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

I was happy to have safe updates disabled for this query, just not permanently off.